# ITextRenderer not parsing < charecters in data while creating pdf

Tags: java, itext

I am using ItextRendered to created pdf. Following it my code

```
ITextRenderer renderer = new ITextRenderer();   
renderer.setDocumentFromString(html);
renderer.layout();
renderer.createPDF(os);
```

Here html is html containing html tags.My problem is when my data contains < in html I get following exception

> [ERROR] Can't load the XML resource (using TRaX transformer).
>   org.xml.sax.SAXParseException: The content of elements must consist of
>   well-formed character data or markup
>   org.xhtmlrenderer.util.XRRuntimeException: Can't load the XML resource
>   (using TRaX transformer). org.xml.sax.SAXParseException: The content
>   of elements must consist of well-formed character data or markup.     at
>   org.xhtmlrenderer.resource.XMLResource$XMLResourceBuilder.createXMLResource(XMLResource.java:191)
>     at org.xhtmlrenderer.resource.XMLResource.load(XMLResource.java:75)
>     at
>   org.xhtmlrenderer.pdf.ITextRenderer.setDocumentFromString(ITextRenderer.java:158)
>     at
>   org.xhtmlrenderer.pdf.ITextRenderer.setDocumentFromString(ITextRenderer.java:153)

Please help me how to solve this problem
Thanks in adavnce

Comment: Can you add a representative part of your html that reproduces the error?

Answer (score 0):

Finally solved my problem by parsing my html using Jsoup here is my solution code.

```
 private String parseSpecialCharactersInData(String string){
         org.jsoup.nodes.Document document =Jsoup.parse(string);
         return document.html();
    }
```

Answer (score -1):

Looks like there's either something wrong with the html string or the method is incorrect. Perhaps try:

```
ITextRenderer renderer = new ITextRenderer();   
renderer.setDocument(File htmlFile); //Put your html string in a .html file
renderer.layout();
renderer.createPDF(os);
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I have done changes as per your suggestion but still I am getting the same error.